# Assigning an array to a constructor

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

So i have an object of multiple dice and im trying to pass an array to it to assign all the dice at once

```
public DiceCollection(int numDice, int[] diceNumSides) {
    this.numDice = numDice;
    this.diceNumSides = diceNumSides;
    Die[] dice = new Die[];
    for (int i = 0; i < numDice; i++){
        dice[i] = new Die(diceNumSides[i]);
    }
}
```

and it turns up in 3 errors at "Die[] dice = new Die[];"

- Array dimension missing
- Incompatible types: Die cannot be converted to Die[]
- Local Variable hides a field

this is the rest of the code if anybody is interested

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class DiceCollection {
        private int numDice,diceNumSides[];
        Die[] dice;

    public DiceCollection(int numDice, int[] diceNumSides) {
        this.numDice = numDice;
        this.diceNumSides = diceNumSides;
        Die[] dice = new Die[];
        for (int i = 0; i < numDice; i++){
            dice[i] = new Die(diceNumSides[i]);
        }
    }

    public int sumDice(){
        int sumSides = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numDice; i++){
            sumSides = sumSides + dice[i];
        }
        return sumSides;
    }    
}
```

Comment: `Die[] dice = new Die[numDice]`. Rename local variable `dice` to something else

Comment: Note that in modern English *dice* is the plural **and** singular form. The word *die* is old and not used in modern text anymore. (compare to [oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/die))

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Array dimension missing

Arrays are always of **fixed-length**. You need to specify their size at construction (and can't change it later anymore). You wrote

```
Die[] dice = new Die[];
```

but you need to write something like

```
Die[] dice = new Die[5];
```

for an array that has place for `5` dice. In your case probably

```
Die[] dice = new Die[numDice];
```

If you need a variable length you might use implementations of the `List` class, like `ArrayList` (which internally uses array techniques).

```
List<Die> dice = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

> 2. Incompatible types: `Die` cannot be converted to `Die[]`

This error is a follow-up of the first error. It will be fixed when you specify the length.

---

> 3. Local Variable hides a field

This warning complaints about your variable names being equal to the names of some member variables (fields), like

```
this.diceNumSides = diceNumSides;
```

Here you have a local variable called `diceNumSides` and a field named `diceNumSides` too (same holds for `numDice` and `dice`). This means you must use `this` in order to address the field, like you correctly did in your code.

However, this often is the source of nasty bugs. That's why you get the warning that you may instead choose different names. Frequently used is the leading `m` (*my*) for fields:

```
mDiceNumSides
```

In other languages a leading underscore is commonly used (`_diceNumSides`).

Comment: It should be also noted that `numDice` is redundant, each array has property `length`, e.g. `diceNumSides.length`